# Verifiable Encryption of a Pedersen Commitment

Tags: encryption, zero-knowledge-proofs, commitments, verifiability

Can the Verifiable Encryption of a Discrete Logarithm scheme of the paper https://www.shoup.net/papers/verenc.pdf (page 19) be used to verify that a ciphertext encrypts the same value committed in a Pedersen Commitment?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Say the message is $m$ and the commitment is $C$ such that $C = g^mh^r$. Since you can use verifiable encryption to prove that a given ciphertext encrypts $m$ in relation $g^m = y$ where $g$ and $y$ are also public knowledge, using the Schnorr protocol you can prove that the $m$ in relation $g^m = y$ is same as the $m$ in $C$